# How to check if docker machine exists programmatically?

Tags: bash, docker, docker-machine

I'm using `docker-machine` to manage my cloud servers. I'm writing some bash scripts to automate some tasks. The question is: "How to check in bash script if docker machine with the specific name already exists?". I need some expression to return true if it exists and false if it doesn't.

Thanks

Comment: look at the output of `which docker-machine` and check if that file exists? There should be a better way

Answer (score 13):

Just run it through grep, if a regexp is good enough for you. For example if you have a machine called foo:

```
$ docker-machine ls -q | grep '^foo$'
```

Should work and return 0. The caret matches the start of the line and the space avoids partial matches. If it doesn't match you will get a non-zero return code.

Comment: 10x! That was exactly what I was asking about

Answer (score 9):

You can use something like the following:

```
docker-machine status some-machine 2> /dev/null || echo "Machine does not exists"
```

Comment: I find this solution very clean.

Answer (score 1):

Not a scripting guru but I would do a "`docker-machine help`", if this command runs and the exit code ($?) is zero, the docker-machine executable is available and functioning.
If the return code is 127 (typically this returned by bash for command not found) or anything other than non-zero, you can assume that either docker-machine is not installed or is not running properly.

Comment: @ChandanNayak Thanks for the correction, yeah I meant $?. Updated the answer.